# String interpolation when not using a string literal

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that used string interpolation to build error messages.

```
p "#{vName} is not a defined variable"  => 'xxx is not a defined variable'
```

Another programmer came through and attempted to externalize the string literals to a separate configuration file. Of course, he doesn't get the substitution.

```
p err_string_from_config  => '#{vName} is not a defined variable'
```

I've looked around, but couldn't come up with anything better than converting to sprintf strings and using printf.

Does anybody know how to get the #{} substitution to work on strings that are not double quote literals within the Ruby script?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually Ruby has functionality very similar to John's Python example:

```
$ irb
>> greeting = 'hello %s, my name is %s!'
>> interpolated = greeting % ['Mike', 'John']
=> "hello Mike, my name is John!"
>>
```

This is also useful if your argument is an array constant. If you must use #{} style interpolation you could use eval:

```
>> greeting = 'hi #{name}'    # notice name is not defined yet
>> name = "mike"
>> eval '"' + greeting + '"'
```

The eval approach is going to be much slower than using % style interpolation, so it's a trade-off.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to find a way that didn't involve him modifying the strings.  It's not a big deal, but after he asked about it, I had to see if there was a way to get the #{} substitution to work without it being in a literal string.  Just seemed as though there ought to be a way.

Comment: @John: No problem if I had a dollar for every small mistake... (I actually didn't know Python did this either) ;)
@Mike: I updated my answer with info on how to do this using #{} style interpolation.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about the trick of using eval and wrapping the double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you look at [Liquid templating language](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) which provides more powerful features (e.g. you can reference parameters by name).
Previous example would look like:

```
greeting = Liquid::Template.parse("hello {{your_name}}, my name is {{my_name}}!")
interpolated = greeting.render('your_name' => 'Mike', 'my_name' => 'John')
# => "hello Mike, my name is John!"
```

Comment: thanks, that's good to know about.  It's a bit more than I think we want to add into what is really a fairly simple script (I'm not exactly sure why they felt compelled to externalize the strings for it to be honest).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it, just for the record. A bit clearer imo.

```
gief = '#{later} please'
later = "later"

puts eval(%Q["#{gief}"])
# => later please
```

But honestly, that is *such* a hack. Unless you have a really good reason to use a string, use a proc instead. I always try to use plain ruby instead of evaling strings.

```
gief = Proc.new {|l| "#{l} please" }
later = "later"

puts gief.call(later)
# => later please
```

Comment: Yeah, I certainly tend to agree that using eval is something I would tend to avoid.  If this were part of a larger "system" that needed an error strategy, I'd probably condier the templating solution or turning each message into a Proc (interesting solution by the way). We'll probably use eval.