# Rails iteration variable inside variable in seed.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

Within my seed.rb I'm populating 4 columns with text data from one title-1.txt file.

```
title  = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, '/features/support/titles/title-1.txt'))  

1.upto(4) do |i|
  PressRelease.create(
    :title => title
  )
end
```

I want to populate each column with different content from different txt files (title-1.txt, title-2.txt, ...)

I know I can make this:

```
1.upto(4) do |i|
  PressRelease.create(
    :title => File.read(File.join(Rails.root, '/features/support/titles/title-' + "#{i}" +'.txt'))
  )
end
```

To make it short I've tried changing the title variable into this:
(notice the title-"#{i}")

```
title  = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, '/features/support/titles/title-' + "#{i}" + '.txt'))
```

But I get this error:
Undefined local variable or method `i' for main:Object

Any tip how to make a reusable and short variable that let's me use it in iterations?

-- **UPDATE**  --
This post doesn't have a complete solution, from the answer of @Paul Fioravanti I got an alternate  method to shorten the code. The url must be stored in the variable without the File.open methods, like this:

```
title_url  = '/features/support/titles/title-' + '%s' + '.txt'  

1.upto(4) do |i|
  PressRelease.create(
    :title => File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "#{title_url %i}"))
  )
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution I got from [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/646126/567863), so you can keep the variable short inside your loop, and don't need to define the numbered file when you define the `title` variable:

```
title  = File.read(File.join(Rails.root, '/features/support/titles/title-' + '%s' + '.txt'))
1.upto(4) do |i|
  PressRelease.create(
    :title => title % i
  )
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this message: No such file or directory - /directories/title-%s.txt. But your method works when I store the url in a variable without the File functions. So in the create method I have this|    
:title => File.read(File.join(Rails.root, "#{title_url %i}")), I'll wait some time, if there is not a better answer I'll set yours as accepted.

Comment: Nice catch...should have known that.  If you end up choosing this solution, please edit your question to post the final answer so that others don't need to accidentally use non-tested code in their solutions :-)