# Ruby regular expression to match Ruby string interpolation

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

I am trying to construct a regular expression that will match any Ruby string that contains string interpolation, such as:

```
"This will contain my #{string}"
```

I came up with:

```
/".*#{.*}.*"/
```

but the `#{}` is interpreted as interpolation. How can I express `#{}` literally?

Comment: Escape the curly braces.

Comment: This looks like an XY question.

Comment: Yeah, no idea what is really necessary. Perhaps, http://ideone.com/8tanIc?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew escaping `#` symbol is one backslash less :)

Comment: Take a look at http://rubular.com/ if you'd like to try out your regular expression against a test string

Answer (score 0):

You can use single quotes when assigning the string to avoid interpolation and express `#{}` literally:

```
my_template = 'This will contain my #{string}'
# => "This will contain my \#{string}"
```

Or alternatively you can use double quotes and escape the # symbol with a slash (as seen in the return value of the statement above).

---

There's also another [interpolation technique described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/646183/703903) which may be helpful:

```
greeting = 'hello %s, my name is %s!'
interpolated = greeting % ['Mike', 'John']
# => "hello Mike, my name is John!"
```

Then you can detect `%s` with your regex, but still retain the ability to interpolate easily & use the string as a template.

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```regex
#\{([^}]*)\}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- Matches substrings surrounded by `#{....}` structure
- Captures the substring inside the brackets into Capture Group 1
- Does not work recursively

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/vR6mU9/1

**Sample text**

```
This will contain my #{string}
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
Capture group 0: #{string}
Capture group 1: `string`
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  #                        '#'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^}]*                    any character except: '}' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \}                       '}'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```